# Need help deleting from Arraylist with remove

Tags: java, arraylist, contacts

Ok, this is homework.  I have an `arraylist` assignment to add, display, search and remove contacts. My code compiles and I have all of the correct methods that function properly EXCEPT for the `deleteMatch()` method. It compiles and runs, but does not actually remove anything from my `arrayList`. I also need to go back once done and validate input and check for nulls I know, but I can do that easliy, I'm just trying to get the basics in first. Any help with this method would be greatly appreciated.

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ContactDatabase
 {
private ArrayList<Contact> contacts;        // ArrayList of contact
private static final int QUIT = 0;          // Menu choices
private static final int ADD = 1;
private static final int LISTALL = 2;
private static final int SEARCH = 3;
private static final int DELETE = 4;

/**
* Default constructor - make a new ArrayList object with parameter type Contact,,
*/
ContactDatabase()
{     // Initialize the categories.// instantiate your ArrayList here
    contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();


}

/**
* inputContact inputs contact information from the keyboard.
* It then stores this new contact in the contacts ArrayList.
*/
public void inputContact()
{
        Contact myContact;

        Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

        System.out.println("Please enter first name of new person");
         String first = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Please enter last name of new person");
         String last = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Please enter phone number xxxxxxxxxx");
         String phone = input.nextLine();

        System.out.println("Please enter e-mail");
         String email = input.nextLine();

        myContact = new Contact(first, last, phone, email);
         contacts.add(myContact);


        System.out.println("Details recorded:");
         System.out.println(contacts);

}

/**
* displayAll iterates through the ArrayList of contacts and outputs each one
* to the screen.
*/
public void displayAll()
{
    for (Contact entry : contacts)
         System.out.println (entry);

}

/**
* displayMatch inputs a keyword from the user.
* It then iterates through the ArrayList of contacts and outputs each one
* to the screen if the contact information contains the keyword.
*/
public void displayMatch()
{

    if(contacts.isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.println("Sorry, there is no contact information to search.");
        }
    else
        {

            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Please enter the search keyword for or 0 to quit: ");
            String search = input.next().trim().toUpperCase();
            if (search.equals("0") == false)
                {
                    boolean found = false;
                    for(Contact a: contacts)
                        {
                            if((a.getFirst().toUpperCase().equals(search))||(a.getLast().toUpperCase().equals(search))||(a.getPhone().toUpperCase().equals(search))||(a.getEmail().toUpperCase().equals(search)))
                                {
                                   System.out.println("that contact info is: ");
                                   System.out.println("name: " + a.getFirst());
                                   System.out.println("name: " + a.getLast());
                                   System.out.println("phone number: " + a.getPhone());
                                   System.out.println("email: " + a.getEmail());
                                   found = true;
                                 }

                            else
                                {
                                    found = false;
                                    System.out.println("Sorry, that contact can not be found!");
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
}



/**
* deleteMatch inputs a keyword from the user.
* It then iterates through the ArrayList of contacts and asks the user
* if the contact should be deleted, if the contact information contains the keyword.
*/
public void deleteMatch()
{
    if(contacts.isEmpty())
        {
            System.out.println("Sorry, there is no contact information to search.");
        }
    else
        {

            Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
            System.out.print("Please enter the search keyword for or 0 to quit: ");
            String search = input.next().trim().toUpperCase();
            if (search.equals("0") == false)
                {
                    boolean found = false;
                    for(Contact a: contacts)
                        {
                            if((a.getFirst().toUpperCase().equals(search))||(a.getLast().toUpperCase().equals(search))||(a.getPhone().toUpperCase().equals(search))||(a.getEmail().toUpperCase().equals(search)))
                                {
                                   System.out.println("that contact info is: ");
                                   System.out.println("name: " + a.getFirst());
                                   System.out.println("name: " + a.getLast());
                                   System.out.println("phone number: " + a.getPhone());
                                   System.out.println("email: " + a.getEmail());
                                   found = true;
                                   Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
                                   System.out.println("Are you sure you would like to remove this contact?");
                                   String sure = inp.next().toUpperCase();
                                   if (sure.equals("YES"))
                                   {

                                        contacts.remove(a);
                                        System.out.println("Contact removed... ");
                                        displayAll();

                                   }
                                  }



                            else
                                {
                                    found = false;
                                    System.out.println("Sorry, that contact can not be found!");
                                }
                        }
                }
        }
}

// run through the array and look for an item that matches e









    // get keyword input from user to be used in search
    // run through list and look for any Contact that has
    //     the keyword
    // prompt user to make sure they want to delete the
    //     (next/current) Contact you found
    // if yes, delete the Contact



// Main class
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ContactDatabase cdb = new ContactDatabase();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice = ADD;

    // Main menu
    while (choice != QUIT)
    {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Choose from the following:");
        System.out.println("0) Quit");
        System.out.println("1) Add new contact");
        System.out.println("2) List all contacts");
        System.out.println("3) Search contacts by keyword and display");
        System.out.println("4) Search contacts by keyword and remove");
        choice = scan.nextInt();
        switch (choice)
        {
            case ADD:   cdb.inputContact();
                        break;
            case LISTALL: cdb.displayAll();
                        break;
            case SEARCH: cdb.displayMatch();
                        break;
            case DELETE: cdb.deleteMatch();
                        break;
        }
    }
}

    class Contact
{
   private String first, last, phone, email;

   /**
    * Constructors.
    */
   public Contact()
   {
   }

   public Contact(String first, String last, String phone, String email)
   {
      this.first = first;
      this.last = last;
      this.phone = phone;
      this.email = email;
   }

   /*
    * Accessor Methods
    */

   public String getFirst()
   {
      return first;
   }

   public String getLast()
   {
      return last;
   }

   public String getPhone()
   {
      return phone;
   }

   public String getEmail()
   {
      return email;
   }

   /*
    * Mutator Methods
    */
   public void setFirst(String first)
   {
      this.first = first;
   }

   public void setLast(String last)
   {
      this.last = last;
   }

   public void setPhone(String phone)
   {
      this.phone = phone;
   }

   public void setEmail(String em)
   {
      this.email = em;
   }



   /*
    * Return all fields concatenated into a string
    */
   public String toString()
   {
      return last + ", " + first + ". " + phone + ", " + email;
   }


   public boolean equals(Object otherObject)
   {
      if (otherObject ==null)
      {
         return false;
      }
      else if (getClass() != otherObject.getClass())
      {
         return false;
      }
      else
      {
         Contact otherContact = (Contact)otherObject;
         return (first.equals(otherContact.first) &&
               last.equals(otherContact.last)&&
               phone.equals(otherContact.phone)&&
               email.equals(otherContact.email));
      }
   }

} // end inner class, Contact
} // end class, ContactDatabase
```

Thank you to everyone for your help. I finally got it to work!!! Here is the final code:

```
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.regex.Matcher;
import java.util.regex.Pattern;

/**
* The ContactDatabase class stores each contact in an arraylist.
* Methods exist to add new contacts, search contacts, delete, and print contacts
* to the console.
*/
public class ContactDatabase
{
private ArrayList<Contact> contacts;        // ArrayList of contact
private static final int QUIT = 0;          // Menu choices
private static final int ADD = 1;
private static final int LISTALL = 2;
private static final int SEARCH = 3;
private static final int DELETE = 4;

/**
* Default constructor - make a new ArrayList object with parameter type Contact,,
*/
ContactDatabase()
{
    contacts = new ArrayList<Contact>();
}
/**
* inputContact inputs contact information from the keyboard.
* It then stores this new contact in the contacts ArrayList.
*/
public void inputContact()
{
    Contact myContact;
    String first = "null";
    String last = "null";
    String phone = "000-0000000";
    String email = "xxx@example.com";
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);

    while (true)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter first name of new person");
        first = input.nextLine();
        if (first == null)
        {
            System.out.println("Sorry, first name cannot be null!");
        }
        else
        {
        break;
        }
    }

    while (true)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter last name of new person");
        last = input.nextLine();
        if (first == null)
        {
            System.out.println("Sorry, last name cannot be null!");
        }
        else
        {
        break;
        }
    }

    while (true)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter phone number 540-555-1212");
        String vphone = input.nextLine();
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("\\d{3}-\\d{3}-\\d{4}");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(vphone);
        if ((matcher.matches())|| vphone != null)
        {
            System.out.println("Thank you.");
            phone = vphone;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Sorry, that entry is incorrect or null");
        }
    }

    while (true)
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter e-mail xyz@xyz.com");
        String vemail = input.nextLine();
        Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile(".+@.+\\.[a-z]+");
        Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher(vemail);
        if ((matcher.matches())||(vemail != null))
        {
            System.out.println("Thank you.");
            email = vemail;
            break;
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Sorry, that entry is incorrect");
        }
    }

    myContact = new Contact(first, last, phone, email);
    contacts.add(myContact);

    System.out.println("Details recorded:");
    System.out.println(contacts);

}

/**
* displayAll iterates through the ArrayList of contacts and outputs each one
* to the screen.
*/
public void displayAll()
{
    System.out.println("Current contact list entries:");
    for (Contact entry : contacts)
    System.out.println (entry);
}
/**
* displayMatch inputs a keyword from the user.
* It then iterates through the ArrayList of contacts and outputs each one
* to the screen if the contact information contains the keyword.
*/
public void displayMatch()
{
    boolean found = false;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.print("Please enter the search keyword for or 0 to quit: ");
    String search = input.next().trim().toUpperCase();
    if (search.equals("0") == false)
    {
        for(Contact a: contacts)
        {
            if((a.getFirst().toUpperCase().equals(search))||(a.getLast().toUpperCase().equals(search))||(a.getPhone().toUpperCase().equals(search))||(a.getEmail().toUpperCase().equals(search)))
            {
                System.out.println("that contact info is: ");
                System.out.print("name: " + a.getFirst());
                System.out.println(" " + a.getLast());
                System.out.println("phone number: " + a.getPhone());
                System.out.println("email: " + a.getEmail());
                found = true;
            }
            if(contacts.isEmpty())
            {
                System.out.println("Sorry, there is no contact information to search.");
            }
        }
    }
    if (found == false)
    {
        System.out.println("Sorry, no such contact");
    }
}
/**
* deleteMatch inputs a keyword from the user.
* It then iterates through the ArrayList of contacts and asks the user
* if the contact should be deleted, if the contact information contains the keyword.
*/
public void deleteMatch()
{
    for (int i=0; i< contacts.size(); i++)
    {
        displayMatch();
        Scanner inp = new Scanner(System.in);
        System.out.println("Are you sure you would like to remove this contact?");
        String sure = inp.next().toUpperCase();
        if (sure.equals("YES"))
        {
            contacts.remove(i);
            System.out.println("Thank you. Contact removed.");
            displayAll();
        }
    }
}

// Main class
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    ContactDatabase cdb = new ContactDatabase();
    Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
    int choice = ADD;

    // Main menu
    while (choice != QUIT)
    {
        System.out.println();
        System.out.println("Choose from the following:");
        System.out.println("0) Quit");
        System.out.println("1) Add new contact");
        System.out.println("2) List all contacts");
        System.out.println("3) Search contacts by keyword and display");
        System.out.println("4) Search contacts by keyword and remove");
        choice = scan.nextInt();
        switch (choice)
        {
            case ADD:   cdb.inputContact();
                        break;
            case LISTALL: cdb.displayAll();
                        break;
            case SEARCH: cdb.displayMatch();
                        break;
            case DELETE: cdb.deleteMatch();
                        break;
        }
    }
}

/**
 * The inner class, Contact, stores the details for a single contact.
 *  There is no error checking on any of the input.  Whatever string is
 *  passed in for a given attribute is accepted.
 */
class Contact
{
   private String first, last, phone, email;

   /**
    * Constructors.
    */
   public Contact()
   {
   }

   public Contact(String first, String last, String phone, String email)
   {
      this.first = first;
      this.last = last;
      this.phone = phone;
      this.email = email;
   }

   /*
    * Accessor Methods
    */

   public String getFirst()
   {
      return first;
   }

   public String getLast()
   {
      return last;
   }

   public String getPhone()
   {
      return phone;
   }

   public String getEmail()
   {
      return email;
   }

   /*
    * Mutator Methods
    */
   public void setFirst(String first)
   {
      this.first = first;
   }

   public void setLast(String last)
   {
      this.last = last;
   }

   public void setPhone(String phone)
   {
      this.phone = phone;
   }

   public void setEmail(String em)
   {
      this.email = em;
   }



   /*
    * Return all fields concatenated into a string
    */
   public String toString()
   {
      return last + ", " + first + ". " + phone + ", " + email;
   }


   public boolean equals(Object otherObject)
   {
      if (otherObject ==null)
      {
         return false;
      }
      else if (getClass() != otherObject.getClass())
      {
         return false;
      }
      else
      {
         Contact otherContact = (Contact)otherObject;
         return (first.equals(otherContact.first) &&
               last.equals(otherContact.last)&&
               phone.equals(otherContact.phone)&&
               email.equals(otherContact.email));
      }
   }

} // end inner class, Contact
} // end class, ContactDatabase
```

Comment: It looks like it should work.  How do you know it does not work? Is it possible you have some duplicates in your contact list? Would it be more appropriate to use a Set instead of a List?

Comment: You've provided 330 lines of code, when you're saying only one method fails. Please edit it to a *short* but complete program which *only* demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Aren't you getting a ConcurrentModificationException?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have overridden the equals method you dont need to check for individual fields , yoy can simply create a new contact with new information and then just call arrayList.remove(contact_ob); it will remove if it exists,

also for comparing string you are using string.toUpper().equals(other_str); instead you can use string.equalsIgnoreCase(otherString) , will compare irrespective of the case

Answer (score 0):

you are trying to remove(object) which is not correct.
Remove the object based on the index or counter... Tis will surely solve your problem.

And between when u try to remove the objct based on the object

This will solve your problem for now,, but think about overriding the equals method and remove the object

Answer (score 0):

There are few things that you need to change in this code.

1] Match with equalsIgnoreCase. Never convert a value to upper or lower case and then match it. It constraints the user to enter a specific case.

2] While entering you need to check for duplicate values which have already been entered.

3] You need to break once you have searched for a particular contact and removed it.

4] Always make a Contact object and then use it for match.